# Swift stick UIView to the top of ScrollView and make it fixed

Tags: ios, swift

I have this UIView

```
let showErrors: UIView = { 
    let v = UIView();
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.layer.zPosition = 2
    return v;
}()
```

And i have a scrollView.Now i want to stick this div to the top of my scrollView and keep it there fixed,so if user scrolls down or up `showErrors` will still be visible to him.I don't use storyboards only programmatical approaches please

Comment: you can have yourScrollViews topAnchor to be same as showErrors bottomAnchor

Comment: Just add this view to the `subView` of `UIView`. Don't make this view to the `sunView` of `scrollView`. And you should start `scrollView` y position where showErrors ends

Comment: @Phyber but then scrollView starts from the bottom of showErrors and i don't want,i want showErrors to be inside of scrollView

Comment: @AnuragSharma i don't want scrollView to start where showErrors ends,i want showErrors to be inside of the ScrollView

Comment: The code you've added is irrelevant to your question. The comments that are suggesting you just pin the view to the top of the scrollview is probably the correct approach.

Comment: @papa you can set `showErrors` inside the `scrollView` but then it will be scrollable!  update your question with the code you are setting other objects in you `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want a view to scroll... don’t put it inside a scroll view.

Make it a sibling of the scroll view and pin it to the view. Then just the bottom half of the screen can scroll and your image will stick at the top.

Answer (score -1):

I got the result by setting `showErrors.topAnchor` to the `view.topAnchor`,but leaving `showErrors` as the subview of scrollView